# Cant see Prometheus server on localhost:9090

Tags: prometheus, azure-aks

I followed a tutorial to lauch a prometheus seerver in aks.
After the deployment of pods, I run a command : kubectl --namespace monitoring port-forward prometheus-server 9090

But when i check in the browser I have no access to the local page of prometheus.
I want to precise that i did all step il azure cloudshell.

Somebody has solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to deploy Prometheus.

It would be helpful if you were to include a link to the tutorial that you're following.

It's possible that the deployment was unsuccessful.

Can you enumerate the resources in the `monitoring` Namespace?

```sh
kubectl get all --namespace=monitoring
```

Are the Pods all running? If not, that's the first problem.

In the list of Services (`kubectl get services --namespace=monitoring`), is there a service that exposes `9090/tcp`? If so, this is likely the Prometheus service that you wish to use.

Is it named `prometheus-server`?

I've deployed [`kube-prometheus`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus) to a Kubernetes cluster and the Prometheus web client is accessed through a service named `prometheus-k8s`:

```sh
kubectl port-forward service/prometheus-k8s --namespace=monitoring 9090
```

Comment: Try `kubectl port-forward service/prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus --namespace=monitoring 9090`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoDqxm7ybLc I followed this tutorial, all pods are in running state. The pod of the server is well exposed in 9090 port. when I write de command line , I use the right name. After the command I just obtain: Forwarding 127.0.0.1:9090 -> 9090 and when I check : http:localhost:9090 I have nothing

Comment: I used your command and nothing :( , The problem can from the fact that I use Cloudshell in Azure ?

Comment: Yes, if you're using a cloud shell then you can't directly access `kubectl port-forward`'s running in it (the port is forwarded to the cloud shell host while your browser is running on your host). You'd need to do a further redirect to port forward to the cloud shell instance too.